# How to call a JavaScript function from C# code

Tags: asp.net

I need to call a javascript function from C# code after page Load, or is it there any way that I can do this on .aspx page itself??

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Guys for your answers as I mentioned I need to call the function after page load I did in a simple way, added that function in <Head> and call that function after page body...and it works..Thanx to all, so it done on .aspx page itself :)

Answer (score 2):

try with   [RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerstartupscript.aspx)

E.g:

```
 RegisterStartupScript("Msg1", "<script language='javascript'> alert('Hello World')  </script>");
```

Comment: +1 because I didn't know about the existance of this short version compared to the `ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` method. Looks like it's the same as calling `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "key", "MyFunc();", true);`, but much shorter, and more *readable*

Answer (score 1):

```
string script = "..." // your script here without <script> tags
ClientScript.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "key", script, true)
```

Also if you want to use it directly from the .aspx you can use jquery

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    //... your script here
});
```

Comment: You might want to replace `RegisterClientScript` with `RegisterClientScriptBlock`, since no `RegisterClientScript` method exists

Answer (score 1):

You can use this,

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "script", 
   "urfunction()", true);
```